# How to use woocommerce_trash_{$post_type} action hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to read product value when admin click on trash for a product (image attached).

[image]

After some searching i found that `woocommerce_trash_{$post_type}` hook can be use for this purpose.

I found the details on [class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.307) line 307 @version 3.0.0

And I applied the code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_trash_product', 'My_custom_trash_product');
function My_custom_trash_product($product_id) {
    error_log(print_r($product_id, true));
}
```

But it is not firing. I am using WooCommerce 6.0.0. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [Trash/delete product hooks don't fire](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/13852)

> We don't control the WordPress UI delete and trash functionality, so
> it bypasses CRUD completely.
>
> If you need to detect these events across CRUD and across WordPress
> UI, use `wp_trash_post` and `wp_delete_post` actions. If we ever have our
> own UI (not WP UI) we'll be able to consistently fire them everywhere.

So alternatively you can use:

```php
/**
 * Fires before a post is sent to the Trash.
 *
 * @since 3.3.0
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID.
 */
function action_wp_trash_post( $post_id ) {
    error_log( print_r( $post_id, true ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_trash_post', 'action_wp_trash_post', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @7uc1f3r for your reply. It is working & I also found a another action hook `trashed_post` [from here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/trashed_post/) which fires after a post is sent to the trash.

I submitted my solution here -

```php
/**
 * Fires after a post is sent to the Trash.
 *
 * @since 2.9.0
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID.
 */
function action_trashed_post( $post_id ) {
    error_log( print_r( $post_id, true ) );
}
add_action( 'trashed_post', 'action_trashed_post', 10, 1 );
```